# Is it possible to eliminate the inner sum to evaluate numerically?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, quantum-mechanics

Any hints on how to simplify the following double sum to be able to find the sum at least numerically?

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac1{n(n^2-1)} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k-1/n)^{2n-2}}{(k+1/n)^{2n+2}}$$

Series comes from quantum mechanics (2nd order perturbation theory).

Comment: May I suggest changing the index of the inner summation and a slight argument change: $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac1{n(n^2-1)} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k-1/n)^{2n-2}}{(k+1/n)^{2n+2}}$$ It doesn't change anything but it might be easier to manipulate some binomial identities for others with more experience.

Comment: @Xoque55 Oh sure, thanks, changed.

Comment: @SBareS Yes, probably a typo, for 50-50 I get 0.00919988. Seems really the convergence is quick - however in case of chopping I would like to make some estimates. P.S Yes, 0.009206 also in Mathematica:-)

Comment: @wondering indeed a typo. I put it into Maple now, and it gives 0.009206 with n capped at 200 and k at 50